# Understanding Box Plots in Seaborn

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, boxplot

I have the following piece of code:

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.boxplot(y=tips["total_bill"])
```

which produces the following plot: [Demo Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkV8D.png)
I referred [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/statistics/boxplots.htm) article to understand how a boxplot demonstrates the distribution of data. 
In a boxplot, the uppermost horizontal line is considered to be the maximum and the lowermost horizontal line is considered to be the minimum. My question is: Why is the horizontal line not at 50.81 and at around 40 instead. I know the answer might be simple, but I have no prior knowledge of boxplot and have referred the above article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper horizontal line should usually be (75th percentile + 1.5 IQR) of your data and the lower one is (25th percentile - 1.5IQR). Here IQR stands for inter-quartile range, which is the length of your box). In box plot, anything outside of the upper and lower whiskers are considered outliers, which are then labeled by the dots in your demo plot.

Comment: If that's the case, then what do the upper, middle and lower lines in the rectangle represent. According to the article I read, the upper side of the rectangle should be 75th percentile, line inside the rectangle should be median and the lower side of the rectangle should be the 25th percentile. If the uppermost line and lowermost line are representing 75th and 25th percentile respectively, then what do the lines inside the rectangle represent?

Comment: @Ronith My bad! I wrote the wrong answer! Updated it!